# ¿Como escapar con jQuery etiquetas HTML excepto <br>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Necesito escapar con jQuery todas las etiquetas HTML excepto `<br>`, encontré el siguiente código pero me escapa todas las etiquetas:

```
var tagsToReplace = {
    '&': '&amp;',
    '<': '&lt;',
    '>': '&gt;'
};

function replaceTag(tag) {
    return tagsToReplace[tag] || tag;
}

function safe_tags_replace(str) {
    return str.replace(/[&<>]/g, replaceTag);
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias

Comment: Seré curioso, pero ¿por que los `<br>` no?

Comment: Traigo de la base de datos los textos y necesito conservar los saltos de linea. En ocasiones los miembros escriben cosas que los navegadores interpretan como HTML y se produce el error, por eso. Saludos

Comment: Haz un triple reemplazo que cambie primero todos los `<br>, <BR>, <br />` etc a un valor temporal como `[|MIBR|]` y luego de aplicar el reemplazo que te propones devuelves `[|MIBR|]'` a `<br>` no es eficiente, pero te evita hacer una expresión regular que luce complicada. Ten presente que `<br>` admite varias escrituras con cierre y espacio dentro de la etiqueta y puede tener una, dos o ninguna mayúscula.

Comment: @quevedo Gracias por tu respuesta, preferiria resolverlo con expresiones regulares. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La regex que puedes usar para ello debería ser algo así, utilizando negative lookahead `(?! )`:

`/<(?!br\s*\/?)[^>]+>/g`

```js
var code = '<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/><title>Your Website</title></head><body><header><nav><ul><li>Your menu</li></ul></nav></header><section><article><header><h2>Article title</h2><p>Posted on <time datetime="2009-09-04T16:31:24+02:00">September 4th 2009</time> by <a href="#">Writer</a> - <a href="#comments">6 comments</a></p></header><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p></article><article><header><h2>Article title</h2><p>Posted on <time datetime="2009-09-04T16:31:24+02:00">September 4th 2009</time> by <a href="#">Writer</a> - <a href="#comments">6 comments</a></p></header><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus<br />et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p></article></section><aside><h2>About section</h2><p>Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper.<br>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p></aside><footer><p>Copyright 2009 Your name</p></footer></body></html>';

code = code.replace(/<(?!br\s*\/?)[^>]+>/ig, '');

console.log(code);
```

Comment: Hola @César, te comento que por ejemplo cuando aparece <b sigue saltándoselo. Gracias

Comment: No entiendo a qué te refieres con <b, ¿puedes poner un ejemplo del HTML a escapar?

Comment: Error mio, disculpa. Gracias!